# Is every odd order skew-symmetric matrix singular?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, skew-symmetric-matrices

We call a square matrix $A$ a *skew-symmetric* matrix if $A=-A^T$. A matrix is said to be *singular* if its determinant is zero. Is every odd order skew-symmetric matrix with complex entries singular?

Answer (score 7):

Yes, that holds, since: $$\det A=\det{(-A^T)}=(-1)^{odd}\det{A^T}=-\det A,$$ from where we get $\det{A}=0$.

Answer (score 1):

This is actually the case :

Suppose, $A$ is an $n\times n$-matrix.

We have $$\det(A)=\det(-A^T)=(-1)^n\cdot \det(A^T)=(-1)^n\cdot \det(A)$$

Since $n$ is odd, we can conclude $\ \det(A)=-\det(A)\ $ implying $\ \det(A)=0\ $

Comment: But the problem here is that the entries are complex. Is it true for complex entries as well?

Comment: Yes, it is also true for complex entries. The proof does not assum real entries.

Answer (score -1):

Consider the example
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
    0 & i & -3\\
    -i & 0 & 2i\\
    3 & -2i & 0\\
\end{bmatrix}
$$

Comment: I mean a 3 by 3 matrix with rows (0 i -3), ( -i 0 2i) and (3 -2i 0).

Comment: If this was intended to be a counterexample, then it is not! The determinant of this matrix is zero.